# Facebook PHP API: $facebook->api('/me') always return info

Tags: facebook, api

For some reason when i check if a user is logged in Facebook, an I make an api call on $facebook->api('/me'); to check if access token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook, i can see the user info even if I logged out from facebook page (in another tab), and i cant determine if a user logged out from facebook.

```
public function __construct() {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $this->_fbappid,
        'secret' => $this->_fbappsecret,
        'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $this->_facebook = $facebook;
}

public function checkFacebookLogin() {
    try {
        $user = $this->_facebook->getUser();
        $user_profile = $this->_facebook->api('/me','GET');
        return true;
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        return null;
   }
```

}

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clear the persistent data before checking for the user

```
facebook->clearAllPersistentData()
```

If you want to check for the status you should redirect the user to login_status.php by using the method:

```
facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params)
```

Get a login status URL to fetch the status from Facebook.

The parameters:

- ok_session: the URL to go to if a session is found
- no_session: the URL to go to if the user is not connected
- no_user: the URL to go to if the user is not signed into facebook

Comment: ok, using facebook->clearAllPersistentData() works but just in the page after login button. If i visit some other pages and then turn back in the app page, it return me again the login button (obviously if you clear all persistent data :)) and it isn't so good. i can't use second solution because i have just a php page with facebook app, so i can't use other urls. But i can't understand why the API return me the user info! Make an api call after calling getUser() should not say that the token is not valid (if the user logged out)? Why Api doesnt' catch the exception?